# How to detach the associated record in memory only which is related to has_many association in rails-4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In ***Rails 3.2.16*** we are having association as **user *has_many* activities** while querying has_many association, we can detach the association in memory by using the pop method which will not update the database, once we reloading the main object then it will remove changes in memory.

```
**Rails 3.12.16**

@user = User.find(1) # Identifying the user
@user.activities # Fetching activities of that user having one record
[#<Activity id: 205501, title: "Logging", user_id: 1, created_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:23", updated_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:43">]

@user.activities.pop # will detach the first object and @activities will have an empty array in the whole application until reloading main object
[]

@user.activities # will return []
@user.activities.build(id: 1234567, title: "Signing Out") # will return only new built object
[#<Activity id: 1234567, title: "Signing Out", user_id: 1>]


@user.reload
@user.activities # will retain the association records
[#<Activity id: 205501, title: "Logging", user_id: 133, created_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:23", updated_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:43">]

**Rails 4.2**

@user = User.find(1) # Identifying the user
@user.activities # Fetching activities of that user
[#<Activity id: 205501, title: "Logging", user_id: 133, created_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:23", updated_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:43">]

@user.activities.pop # will throw an error because ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy is not having the pop method

# So we tried the to_a method
@user.activities.to_a.pop # it is affecting the array but not detaching the association in memory due it is not mutated
[]

@user.activities # > Rails 4 the association is reloaded defaultly
[#<Activity id: 205501, title: "Logging", user_id: 133, created_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:23", updated_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:43">]

# If we are trying to build a new object
@user.activities.build(id: 1234567, title: "Signing Out")

@user.activities # We are receiving both existing and new build object but we needed only newly build object like rails 3
[#<Activity id: 205501, title: "Logging", user_id: 133, created_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:23", updated_at: "2020-06-01 14:29:43">,
 #<Activity id: 1234567, title: "Signing Out", user_id: 1>]
```

As Rails Document suggests to use the delete method,
but it is updating the association record in Database and removing the record as well.
Anyone can suggest the replacement of the rails 3.12.16 pop method, in rails 4.2

Currently, we are upgrading our Ruby on Rails application from 3 to 4,2.

Gems Listing:-

```
Rails 4.2.0 -
1) ruby (2.3.3)
2) activerecord (4.2.0)

Rails 3.2.16 - 
1) ruby (2.0.0)
2) activerecord (3.2.16)
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using the `pop` method? Do you just want the most recent activity for that user?

Comment: No, I want to detach the associated record i.e., need to remove the activity from that @user in memory only it shouldn't affect the database. In Rails 3.2.16 we are ```@user.activities``` will have one record associated if we are executing ```@user.activities.pop``` the first record will remove and if I am executing ```@user.activities``` it will return us the empty once we reload user i.e., ``` @user.reload``` the association will be retained this activity

Comment: I apologize, perhaps my question wasn't clear. What does "remove the activity from that @user in memory" _accomplish_? _Why_ are you doing this?

Comment: Thanks for your response & apologies for my question wasn't clear. I want to remove the associated object and assigning a new object in memory by not affecting the database. I updated the description for more clearance.

Comment: See my answer below. The problem you're experiencing is how `pop` _should_ work, but didn't in older versions of rails. From the link below: "you should not assume that mutating `to_a` would mutate the relation."

Answer (score 1):

According to a rails contributor, this is expected behavior.

See here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/30612#issuecomment-329884753

I suspect you're going to have to find a different way to do what you want to do, but you haven't really stated what you're trying to accomplish.